# Why is Canon EF 24-105 available at different prices on Amazon?

Tags: lens, canon, pricing

I am very interested about this Canon lens. However, I found it on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=canon%2024-105&rh=i:aps,k:canon%2024-105) at three different prices, ranging from $840 to $1056. What is the difference between the three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all the same lens, they are just being sold by different sellers who have set their own price, presumably based on the discount they got from the wholesaler.

Comment: Good to know. I also found out that the 70-200mm (L series) can be found for less than $600 on google shop. You would spend as twice as much on Canon website. That's strange.

Comment: The manufacturer will generally sell at RRP. Wholesale discount off that will probably be in the region of 50-60%, and retailer discount 40% tops. It just depends how much margin the retailer is willing to sacrifice to get the sale.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the cheaper lenses there are refurbished units, some are secondhand, some are also 'grey market imports' 
Generally speaking, stores (in this case, in the US) will charge more than stores in China/Japan for various reasons.

With regards to your finding the 70-200mm lens, there are actually 5 versions of this lens. If you can find the 70-200mm f/2.8 IS II USM for under $1,500 you've scored an amazingly good deal.
There are incremental differences in some of the lenses and in others there are quite large ones. The change from a maximum aperture of f/4 to f/2.8 in the newer models for example.

Hope that helps clear things up.